# Why `cat file1 file2 > file2` command fall into endless loop?

Tags: shell, terminal, cat

When executing command `cat file1 file2 > file2` in terminal at Mac 10.11, it will fall into endless loop. I was expected file1 content is add to the head of file2 and write it into file2.

Why is that happening?

Update:

As *Benjamin W.* mentioned, I think the reason is the input file and output file has been set to the same file. But why `cat file1 file2 > file1` will not hang with endless loop?

Comment: You are reading/writing `file2` in the same operation, use a `tmp` file `cat file1 file2 > tmp && mv -f tmp file2`

Comment: Endless loop, really? My Bash stops with an error "input file is output file". If it wouldn't, I'd expect it to truncate `file2`, than cat `file1` and `file2` to the empty `file2`, with the same result as `cp file1 file2`, which isn't what you want either.

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/154903/38906